# 'Disable' segue for post with a conditional value iOS/ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, firebase, segue

here is my situation,

on my app, I get a list of post being display by a tablew view. on click, it bring to a postdetail view via this segue:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
}
```

With Firebase, some of my post has a condition `published` with boolean value ( true / false )

I 'd like somehow, if the value is on false, to disable the segue. As some posts have a 'COMING SOON' title, nothing should happen on click of those posts.

Do you know how is that possible to do by any chance ? Will be lovely !

Thanks a lot !

EDIT --

That the structure of my DB where you can see the published condition[image]

Comment: Why don't you use something like if(!post.content.contains('ComingSoon'){ //performSegue } ?

Comment: hm, the idea is to not have the segue working, how can you 'disable' it ? Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard posts[indexPath.row].title != "COMING SOON" else {
            return
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: hmm I just noticed, it doesn't segue to the good data for the other posts  !!!  Any idea why :( ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "disable" a segue, but you can prevent it to be performed using a conditional if statement in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    // get post info
    let post = myArrayOfPosts[selectedIndexPath]
    // check if post is COMING SOON
    if post.title != "COMING SOON"{
        // if not, trigger the segue            
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
    }
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I would recommend to store the "COMING SOON" string value in a constant in your class, or maybe in an `Enum` if you have other titles for which you want a different behavior.

**EDIT:** I've fixed the if statement which I incorrectly wrote in the first place. I cannot comment on posts yet (lack of reputation), so hopefully you see this edit :)